# Xcode 8 - UIToolbar height is shown as 1000(CGFloat)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitoolbar, xcode8

My app consist of `webView` and `toolbar`. So I have to subtract `screenheight` with toolbar height to get the height of `webView` like:

```
webviewHeight = screenHeight - Toolbarheight;
```

But the toolbar height is shown as 1000. So `webviewHeight` is negative and my app crashing.

This was working fine on earlier version of Xcode before Xcode8. Is this because of the change in Storyboard?

Is there a way to get the correct height of toolbar.

Comment: any solution you got?

Answer (score 0):

This is Xcode 8 design issue and you fixed this problem two way

1. you check your toolbar Autoresizeing class and chenge like this
   [image]

and

2. second way is you **specify your UIToolBar height in viewController** .

toolBar.frame.size.height = 50

Comment: using 2nd way it shows error expression is not assignable.